# How to hide the my one-off fork repo in Github?

Tags: github

How to hide my one-off fork repo in Github?

I've forked the public repo, make the changes and pull request back to the parent repo. The parent repo owner merged my request.

My forked repo is one-off, I don’t want to see it in my list.

Can I hide it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

1. **Delete remote, leave local**

You can "hide" the repository from your GitHub profile by deleting the repository from GitHub, but leaving the local repository on your computer (or somewhere else).

You can then later re-add that local repo to GitHub if needed.

2. **Make it private**

You can make the repository [private](https://github.com/pricing) (by first [duplicating](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/) it) so that *others* won't see it on your profile, but it's still there, only you can see it.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way is to create a repository and then import the repo.

1. Click on `new repository`
2. In the top click on `Import a repository`
3. Now paste the clone link of the repo that you want to fork and choose `private repo`

Done!

Answer (score 5):

You have to remove the repository (fork).  This is available in the repository settings.

https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository/

Comment: Yes, I can remove. But can I *hide*?

Comment: No, you can't hide the repository from your public profile.  I often fork something, submit a pull request then remove the repo, I got the impression that's what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 3):

At 08 Nov 2017 Github post a new feature - [archiving-repositories](https://github.com/blog/2460-archiving-repositories)

Read the [doc](https://help.github.com/articles/archiving-repositories/). Now you can move your unused and one-off repos to read-only archive.

Comment: Read-only != hide.

Answer (score 1):

So long as everything in your fork has been merged into the parent repo, there's no harm in deleting your fork.